# Website for Mobile Devices - Using Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, mobile, windows-mobile, mobile-website, mobilewebforms

I am new to Mobile specific website development. I want to know does Visual Studio provides way to create a web site which can be targeted to mobile devices? Also can this website be run on phones running on OS other than Windows OS like iPhone, Android or slimier other OS?

My aim is to develop a website which can be targeted to phone running on any OS. Does Visual Studio and .NET can be used for this purpose?

If yes then can someone provide me some content to start with.

Thanks
Paresh

Answer (score 1):

Any phone with a web browser can view a web site, regardless of what technology platform that site is written on.  It's one of the best and defining characteristics of the web...

You can certainly code a website for mobile devices with Visual Studio and run it on the .NET platform on IIS (or Mono).

As far as targeting all devices, your man concern should be the UI of the website and how it will render in each phone's browser.  I'd recommend an approach of making the site look good for the most popular platforms first (iPhone's Safari, Android's browser), and making it 'good enough' for the rest.